# Клик по нулевому элементу

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Код кликает по всем элементам, но мне нужно кликнуть по нулевому элементу - `match[0].click()` не работает и выбивается ошибка `'WebElement' object is not subscriptable`.

```
for match in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match-static.event__match--twoLine"):
    match.click()
```

Comment: WebElement это не список, а фрагмент html-кода. потому и не работает.

Comment: @Эникейщик, и что мне можно с этим сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел решение в одну строчку:

```
match = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
```